# Select same table name from all databases in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this dynamic query, that is union from all my databases (that is start with "Db") the same table ("Tbl_SameTable").

```
DECLARE @tableName nvarchar(256) = 'Tbl_SameTable'
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

SELECT @sql = @sql + CASE WHEN @sql <> '' THEN 'UNION ALL ' ELSE '' END 
                   + 'SELECT * FROM [' + dbs.name + ']..[' + @tableName + '] '
FROM sys.sysdatabases dbs
WHERE left(dbs.name,2) = 'Db'

EXEC(@sql)
```

I want to add two things to this query:

1. Add a column of database name
2. Assign the query result to a "temp table" or "table variable"

I do not know if this is important but, the "Tbl_SameTable" is a 5 column table (int, nvarchar, int,nvarchar,nvarchar)

Comment: **Warning**: `'[' + @tableName + ']'` is *not* safe from injection. Use `QUOTENAME` to properly quote your objects.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Be aware that aggregate string concatenation (`@sql = @sql + `) is not guaranteed to work; use `STRING_AGG` in SQL 2017+ or `FOR XML` in earlier versions.

Comment: If you have the same table, with the same definition, in multiple database, that infers you have a design flaw, if I am honest. If you need to treat this data in a single dataset, then the data should be in a single database (and table).

Comment: Dan Guzman, my SQL Server version is 2017

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, however, you'll want something like this. As this is pseudo SQL, you'll need to replace `{Columns}` with the actual names (not `*`) for it to work. For the `CREATE TABLE` you'll need to define the data type of said columns too.

```sql
DECLARE @SchemaName sysname = N'dbo',
        @TableName sysname = N'YourTable';

CREATE TABLE #Temp (DatabaseName sysname,
                    {Columns});

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = STUFF((SELECT @CRLF + N'UNION ALL' + @CRLF +
                         N'SELECT N' + QUOTENAME(d.[name],'''') + N' AS DatabaseName, {Columns}' + @CRLF +
                         N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)
                  FROM sys.databases d
                  WHERE d.[name] LIKE 'Db%'
                  ORDER BY database_id
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,13, N'') + N';'

--PRINT @SQL; --Your Best Friend

INSERT INTO #Temp(DatabaseName, {Columns})
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

And, of course, if it doesn't work your best friend will be there to help you out.

Comment: You could just select it out without inserting to `#Temp`, you can also get the column names from `sys.columns`

Comment: Charlieface, can you post your solution ?

Comment: You could, @Charlieface, but the OP states "I want to... Assign the query result to a "temp table" or "table variable" For the latter, that would require dynamic dynamic SQL; I really didn't want to write any of that today. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using sp_MSforeachdb and adding the results to another table?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmp
CREATE TABLE #tmp (col1 INT, col2 INT,...)

DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
SELECT @command = 'IF ''?'' LIKE ''Db%'' BEGIN USE ? 
   EXEC(''INSERT INTO #tmp (col1, col2,...) SELECT col1, col2,... from Tbl_SameTable'') END' 
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command 

SELECT * FROM #tmp
```